# React-toastify toasts don't close

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

I have a react app and I use `react-toastify` to prompt for certain messages. However, whenever I click the x on the toasts they don't close. They do, however, close when I have `autoClose: delay` configured, as shown below. I can also drag them away and close that way.

Here is a little utility I have created to make a toast:

```
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
export const notifyInfo = (msg, delay = 3000) => {
    toast.info(msg, {
        position: 'top-center',
        autoClose: delay,
        hideProgressBar: false,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined
    });
};
```

And here is how I use it on the component where I want to display the toast:

```
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import * as Msg from '../utils/messaging_utils';
...
...
Msg.notifyInfo("Test Message", 2500);
```

I'd greatly appreciate any pointers on how to make the close on click work.

I'm using the latest react-toastify i.e. version 7.0.4
btw, on downgrading to 6.2.0 I can see the close button work fine.

Comment: What's the z-index of the notify component and the button? Is there any other component where your prompt shows up that might interrupt with the close click?

Try making the close button larger (scale it up), and click on it to see if it closes

Comment: Thanks @SarhadSalam! The z-index of the toast container is 9999. There is no other component overlayed on top that might be interfering with the click event being not passed to the toast. The same setup with an older version of the library (6.2.0) seems to work just fine. For now, I'll just roll back the version. Thanks again for your response.

Answer (score 4):

### Solution:

- import `react toastify css`

```
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```

- `App.js` should import

```
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added the className "toast-custom" and that was colliding with bootstrap class. Fixed updating className

Answer (score 0):

I still have the issue with progress toast on Mozilla (but not Chrome.)
A possible workaround is to set the progress to null and add an autoClose duration.

```js
toast.update(toastMapId, {
            render: `100%`,
            type: 'success',
            hideProgressBar: false,
            autoClose: 1000,
            progress: null,
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

i am getting a same issue and after removing all attribute it working fine.

```
<ToastContainer
    position="top-center"
    autoClose={3000}
  />

toast.success('Login Successful');
```